# Setting Preferred Authentication Method on Spring SFTP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration-sftp

I'm attempting to build an SFTP connection via Spring Boot.  I'm using password authentication rather than PrivateKey.  When I fire up my application it first attempts to authenticate over gssapi-with-mic and Kerberos prompts for credentials.  After I key press through the Kerberos the application then attempts to look for a Private Key.  After not finding any details regarding the key it will finally attempt the credentials supplied to the Session Factory and work as intended.  As this application is going to be living within a Docker build I need it to attempt the password authentication first.

At this point I've attempted to set session properties, setting AllowUnkownKeys to false and removing it entirely with no success.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SFTPConnector {


public static void main(String[] args){
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SFTPConnector.class).run(args);
}

@Bean
Properties configProperties(){
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.setProperty("PreferredAuthenticationMethod", "PASSWORD");
    return config;
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller(){
    System.out.println("Initializing Poller");
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(6000));
    return pollerMetadata;
}
@Bean
SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory(){
    System.out.println("Creating Session");
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("someSFTPServer");
    factory.setUser("user");
    factory.setPassword("SomePassword");
    factory.setPort(22);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setSessionConfig(configProperties());
    return new CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory);
}
@Bean
SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sftpInboundFileSynchronizer(){
    System.out.println("In File Synchronizer");
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sftpSessionFactory());
    fileSync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSync.setRemoteDirectory("SomeDir");
    fileSync.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    return fileSync;
}
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter("sftpChannel")
public MessageSource<File> sftpMessageSource(){
    System.out.println("Inside SFTP Message Source");
    SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("/tmp/local_inbound"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
MessageHandler messageHandler(){
    System.out.println("Inisde Message Handler");
    return new MessageHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> arg0) throws MessagingException {
                File f = (File) arg0.getPayload();
                System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    };
}
```

}`

I'm getting:
019-01-04 11:22:30.938  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
2019-01-04 11:22:30.938  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
2019-01-04 11:22:30.943  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
2019-01-04 11:22:30.948  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
2019-01-04 11:22:30.952  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Authentications that can continue: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2019-01-04 11:22:30.953  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
Kerberos username [bradley.dudra]: 
Kerberos password for bradley.dudra: 
2019-01-04 11:34:28.546  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
2019-01-04 11:34:28.547  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Next authentication method: publickey
2019-01-04 11:34:28.548  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Authentications that can continue: password
2019-01-04 11:34:28.548  INFO 11240 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : Next authentication method: password

After this point the authentication works.
I need to omit the attempt to authenticate via password from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your property in session configuration is wrong:
try with the following :

```
config.setProperty("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
```

have a look at the supported properties [Here](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setConfig-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Made the above change and am now receiving the following error:
2019-01-04 14:18:03.377 ERROR 9028 --- [ask-scheduler-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing '/InternatlPgms/INTO/Archive/Receipt' to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item.

Comment: @NoobWebDev change the method to "password", i updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. That did it